# IIS 8 ASP.NET 4 Default maxWorkerThreads

Tags: iis-8, worker-process

Is there a default for maxWorkerThreads in IIS 8.0 ASP.NET 4?

With IIS 6 I recall there was a maximum number of threads that could execute within a single worker process. Having a tough time finding Microsoft documentation stating what the default is for IIS-8.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/821268

Comment: Thanks your link pointed me to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/07/20/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0/ in there they point out the changes to IIS that have occurred since 1.1. and 2.0. For .Net 4.0 the driver is maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU and the default varies based on the .Net framework version for 4.0 its 5000.

Answer (score 1):

The default is 20 according to the [.NET Framework documentation for MaxWorkerThreads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.processmodelsection.maxworkerthreads(v=vs.110).aspx).